# Error recording to movie file with AVFoundation

Tags: ios4, avfoundation, video-capture, avcapturesession

This is a strange problem.  I have not changed any code involving this in my project but my video recording has randomly stopped working.  When I try to save to a movie to a file I get the following error:

**Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12780.)"**

I start my capture with the following code:

```
- (void)initVideoCapture {
self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

AVCaptureDevice *videoCaptureDevice = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoCaptureDevice error:nil];
[self.captureSession addInput:videoInput];

aMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];    
[self.captureSession addOutput:aMovieFileOutput];
[self detectVideoOrientation:aMovieFileOutput];

[self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];

[self.captureSession startRunning];
```

}

I then call this method from the viewController to start recording:

```
- (void) startRecord {
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSString *newDateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[outputFormatter release];

NSString * fileString = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mov",newDateString]];
recordFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:fileString];        

[aMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordFileURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

}

At this time I get the error in this function.

> - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
>     didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
>     fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error

What is really weird is that it randomly works sometimes.  Like, I will compile the project and it will work 100% of the time.  Next time I compile it will work 0%.  What could I be doing wrong?  Anything obvious?

Answer (score 6):

I've gotten -12780 when the orientation of the device was UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp, UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown and UIDeviceOrientationUnknown.  Since a recoded video's orientation has to be portrait or landscape, it'll error out on you.  I had to write a quick method that checks for those three, and just translates them to portrait.

Comment: You are right.I meet this issue too.Could you tell me how you translate the orientation??I don't know how to change it.It's read-only.Thanks~~

Answer (score -3):

this seems to be a bug with apple.  i solved it by using AVAssetWriter and AVAssetWriterInput

Comment: Can you provide more detail into how you solved this? Thanks!